# Счетчик с шагом -2

Tags: java

Добрый день! Наткнулся на задачку где нужно указать числа от 1000 до 0 с шагом -2, вроде задачка легкая, но Java начал изучать не так давно, да и в других языках оказывается не делал этого.

```
class CountFor{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 1000; i>=0; i-- ) {
            System.out.println("Step " + i);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `i--` -> `i -= 2;` или даже `i = i - 2` для чрезмерной понятности

Comment: Спасибо! То что нужно, как было сказано на этом сайте стыд - не спросить, стыд - не знать.

Comment: Главное, чтобы вы поняли, и у вас не возникло нового вопроса о счётчике с шагом 5 ;)

Comment: @etki, ответы - в ответы.

Answer (score 1):

Всего то добавь декрементацию `i` в строке сисаута:

```
class CountFor{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 1000; i>=0; i-- ) {
            System.out.println("Step " + i--);
        }
    }
}
```

В таком случае переменная `i` будет декрементироваться два раза.

Второй способ - вместо декрементации использовать простое арифметическое вьражение

```
class CountFor{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 1000; i>=0; i -= 2 ) {
            System.out.println("Step " + i);
        }
    }
}
```

Еще можно использовать Stream API:

```
    IntStream.iterate(1000, i -> i - 2)
            .limit(500)
            .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется while лучше подойдет для этого.

```
int i = 1000;
        while (i>0){
            System.out.println(i-=2);
        }
```